# participial clause: hitting Mary on the head

Tags: participle-clauses

It's generally known that a "having + past participle" clause can indicate an event that takes place before the one described by the main clause. There are, however, "Ving" forms that can indicate an earlier event:

> Putting down the newspaper, I walked over to the window. (= After I put down ...)

Here, "putting" is used instead of "Having put."

What kind of verb can indicate an earlier action by assuming a simple Ving form rather than "Having + past participle"?

Are the following sentences okay if the intended meaning is that John ran away **after** he hit Mary?

> Hitting Mary on the head, John ran away.

> Giving Mary a punch on the head, John ran away.

Of course "Having hit Mary ..." and "Having given Mary a punch ..." would work, but there are sentences where the sequence of events can be expressed by simple Ving forms. I'm investigating whether "hit" and "give a punch" are okay in their Ving forms with the intended meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can be correct/natural with context.

He came on them sitting on the bench. Hitting Mary on the head, he ran away.

It's another of case of an 'understood' word - in this case, 'after'.

Without preceding context, the sentences are odd. They clearly have a meaning, but seem to hang, purposeless.

Similarly:

"Yelling at my sister I stormed out of the room"

It conjures up a picture, but is odd with no context.

Comment: Thank you. Are you a native speaker of English?

Comment: @Apollyon yes, I am.